# Pass values and do actions to main ViewController after dismissing all navigation ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a mainViewController, press a button to show vc1 of Navigation VC, then press a button to go to vc2 then vc3, after pressing a button on vc3 of Navigation VC, I want to dismiss whole Navigation VC and use information on vc3 to set things on mainViewController.

Following is my vc3, guess I should add codes before navigationController?.dismiss in @IBAction func onContiuneEditing?

Thank you in advance!

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var photo: Photo! = nil
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var filterLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        imageView.image =  UIImage(data: photo.currentImage)
        dateLabel.text = String(photo.date.description.split(separator: " ")[0])
        filterLabel.text = photo.filter
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func onShare(_ sender: Any) {
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageView.image!], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func onContiuneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
      
        
        navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting up and using an unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)** or **[Protocol Delegates](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/)** if you want to pass data to vc3 to vc1.

Because you have 3 layer in navigation I suggest you use **NotificationCenter**.

Post local notification using NotificationCenter and set a listener in your vc1. And when that listener is execute you can perform your operation.
For ex:

in **PhotoViewController**

```
@IBAction func onContiuneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:CONTINUE_EDITING), object: nil)
  navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

in **vc1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(continueEditing), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: CONTINUE_EDITING), object: nil)
}

func continueEditing() {

}
```